# Does anyone know the word for this situation?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, diction

The situation is when a **writer's verbosity obscures meaning**.

For example, legal books use center-embedding and unnecessary phrases which can be written simpler. This phenomenon only further confuses readers.

Another example of this is in this sentence: "Trying to bridge my thoughts piece-by-piece for the sake of a of part-time job being unsatiated artist, this piece is about supposing gray matter in the brain receiving implants providing vibration and mild electrical shocks could invoke a greater quality of life."

Can anyone assist a humble fellow?

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence where you would use the word? It's not clear what you are looking for. A verb? A noun?

Answer (score 0):

You could call this writing **circuitous,** [defined by The Free Dictionary as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/circuitous)

> Characterized by indirectness, evasiveness, or complexity, as in action or language

Comment: This word is used for the circumvention of answering questions. This is typically seen in news articles or literature that reports info. However, the word I'm looking for is more specific to the indirectness making it's meaning vague.

Comment: "Circuitous" has that exact meaning; it basically means "indirect." It's sometimes used when people don't speak directly as a way of dodging questions. But that's certainly not its only use!

Comment: That sounds about right @alphabet

Answer (score 0):

One word that seem to fit the criteria as per the [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) definitions is:

1. [obfuscate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/obfuscation)

   > - as in to confuse
   >
   >   to make (something) unclear to the understanding
   >
   > > irrelevant matters that only serve to obfuscate the fundamental issue of guilt or innocence

Comment: The two words you provided are used to describe verbosity rather than how verbosity confuses people or makes things unclear. I appreciate the new words you bstowed upon me, though.

Comment: @Elainor Please refresh and see my edit as per your comment not wanting something that implies verbosity but rather someone having the intention to have verbosity cause confusion.

Comment: oh, yes! This actually sounds like the right word! A million thanks.

Comment: @Elainor You are welcome, don't forget to check the mark to the left of my answer if that's what you needed.